# How to get columns of view item of the list in sharepoint

Tags: 2007

In sharepoint 2010 list when right click the item there will be view item in which it shows certain columns and it doesn't depends on the viewID or the default view.How they are shown the view of the item ?

Answer (score 1):

The properties view uses a [`ListFieldIterator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listfielditerator.aspx) class to go through each field and decide which to display.

It decides which columns to display columns based on

- if the Column is Hidden
- if the Column has the ShowInViewForm (for Display views) property
- some other internal Voodoo

If you're looking to replicate this you can probably use the [`ListFieldIterator.IsFieldExcluded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listfielditerator.isfieldexcluded.aspx)  property